# Google Sheets Custom Color for top 10 values when values are not sorted and contain formulas

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm having a problem getting Google Sheets to color the top 10 values in multiple columns.

I have columns that contain the following stock information:

Account,Ticker,Symbol,YTD,1 Yr,5 Yr,10 Yr,Risk,Return,Star Rating

Example:
T. Rowe Price U.S. Large-Cap Core Fund,TRULX,2.2,3.93,12.3,12.67,2,5,5

I would like to color the top 10 values for the 1 Yr, 5 Yr, 10 Yr columns.

I thought the function large(L:L,10) would do the job but it seems that the function needs to be sorted by the field that its coloring and it doesn't seem to work if the values in the column are formulas.  All the data in these fields but the ticker are formulas.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that data column is column A.

Here's step by step solution:

1. select your range, like: `A2:A500`
2. go menu Format → Conditional formatting...
3. Choose 'Format cells if...' = Custom formula is
4. Paste this formula: `=$A2>=large($A$2:$A,10)`

To check if the formula works right, you may use this formula, paste it into empty column:

```
=QUERY(sort(A2:A,1,0),"limit 10")
```

This formula will give you the list of top 10 values from column A. Change A to your column.

Comment: Excellent!! Combining your work and IFERROR I was able to get it to work like I was wanting it to!!! Thanks!